# Decode base64 image in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, base64

I have a Google sheets document with multiple columns. One Column contains an image encoded in base64. I wish to decode the image to display the (decoded) image.

I have tested the validity of the base64 image using https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/base64-decode.html.

When I decode using the "Base64 to Image Decode" option, it decodes the image properly.

When I use the standard decoder ("Base64 Decode") option I get a long string of symbols. I get a similar set of symbols with my sheets formula attempts:

I have tried a few formulas based on some research where "L2" contains the base64 encoded image:

```
=IMPORTDATA("data:image/jpeg;base64,"&L2)
=IMAGE("data:image/jpeg;base64,"&L2)
=IMAGE("data:image/jpeg;base64,"&TEXT(L2, "0"))
```